# code only removes first set of xml nodes not others

Tags: xml, vb.net

I am having some trouble with my code. when I run it it deletes only ever the first set of xml nodes. If I try to delete the second or third it nothing gets deleted. I am reading in xml file also. I dont think my code is looping through properly. I want my code to loop through all of the child nodes and delete the one entered i the text box.Does anyone know the reason as the why this could be happening.

```
Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click

    Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
    doc.Load(path & FileXml)
    Dim Nodes = doc.SelectNodes("//TicketNumber")
    For Each elem As XmlElement In Nodes
        Console.WriteLine(elem.InnerText)

        If elem.InnerText = TextBox1.Text Then
            elem.ParentNode.ParentNode.RemoveChild(elem.ParentNode)
            MessageBox.Show("Element Deleted! ") '& TicketNumber.ToString)           
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    doc.Save(path & FileXml)
End Sub
```

> xml code sample: (note:I could have hundreds lines of xml)

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="us-ascii" standalone="yes"?>
<sales_audit_xml>
  <DataTable>
    <TicketNumber>0145191647504</TicketNumber>
    <Total_Amt>11.39</Total_Amt>
    <Total_Taxes>0.00</Total_Taxes>  
    <Code>SUN1</Code>  
  </DataTable>
  <DataTable>
    <TicketNumber>0145191647505</TicketNumber>
     <Total_Amt>11.39</Total_Amt>
    <Total_Taxes>0.00</Total_Taxes>  
    <Code>SUN1</Code>
  </DataTable>
  <DataTable>
     <TicketNumber>0145192428666</TicketNumber>
     <Total_Amt>13.64</Total_Amt>
    <Total_Taxes>0.00</Total_Taxes>  
    <Code>SUN1</Code>  
  </DataTable>
</sales_audit_xml>
```

> full code

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Text
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Xml.Schema
Imports System.Xml.XPath
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Public Class Form1
    Dim Filetxt As String = "textfile.txt"
    Dim path As String = "filepath"
    Dim FileXml As String = "xmlfile.xml"
    Dim FileXsd As String = "schema.xsd"
    Dim RootEle As String = "sales_audit_xml"
    Dim FirstEle As String = "DataTable"
    Dim lstErrs As New List(Of String)
    Dim strFilNme As String = Me.txtFilNme.Text

    '-----Read in txt file and convert to xml file
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim myText As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(path & Filetxt)
        Dim ary As String() = myText.Split(vbCrLf)
        Dim writer As New XmlTextWriter(path & FileXml, Encoding.ASCII)
        writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented
        writer.Indentation = 4
        writer.WriteStartDocument(True)
        writer.WriteStartElement(RootEle)
        ' data for each element in the array
        For x As Integer = 0 To ary.Length - 1
            Writestudent(writer, ary(x))
        Next
        writer.WriteEndElement()
        writer.WriteEndDocument()
        writer.Close()
    End Sub
    Private Sub Writestudent(ByVal wr As XmlWriter, ByVal str As String)

        Dim ary As String() = str.Split(strDelimiter)

        wr.WriteStartElement("DataTable")
        wr.WriteStartElement("TicketNumber")
        wr.WriteString(ary(0))
        wr.WriteEndElement()
        wr.WriteStartElement("Total_Amt")
        wr.WriteString(ary(1))
        wr.WriteEndElement()
        wr.WriteStartElement("Total_Taxes")
        wr.WriteString(ary(2))
        wr.WriteEndElement()
        wr.WriteStartElement("code")
        wr.WriteString(ary(3))
        wr.WriteEndElement()
        wr.WriteEndElement()

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    '--read file
        Dim reader As XmlReader = Nothing
        Dim fileWriter As IO.StreamWriter = Nothing
        Dim fileInfo As IO.FileInfo = Nothing
        Dim fileWrite As IO.StreamWriter = Nothing

        Dim TicketNumber As String = Nothing
        Dim Total_Amt As String = Nothing
        Dim Total_Taxes As String = Nothing
        Dim code As String = Nothing

    Try

        fileInfo = New IO.FileInfo(strFilNme)

        'create a file in directory and write (errors) to that file
        fileWriter = New IO.StreamWriter(fileInfo.DirectoryName & "\ErrorMessages.txt")

        Dim settings As XmlReaderSettings = New XmlReaderSettings()
        settings.Schemas.Add("namespace", path & FileXsd)
        settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema

        reader = XmlReader.Create(txtFilNme.Text, settings)
        Dim document As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()

        document.Load(reader)

        'validate xml
        Dim eventHandler As ValidationEventHandler = New ValidationEventHandler(AddressOf ValidationEventHandler)
        ' the following call to Validate succeeds.
        document.Validate(eventHandler)
        'add a node so that the document Is no longer valid
        Dim navigator As XPathNavigator = document.CreateNavigator()
        navigator.MoveToFollowing("Difference", "namespace")

        document.Validate(eventHandler)

        reader.Close()


        Dim xdoc As XmlDocument
        Dim nodelist As XmlNodeList

        xdoc = New XmlDocument
        Dim xmlData As String = path & FileXml
        xdoc.Load(xmlData)
        nodelist = xdoc.GetElementsByTagName("DataTable")

        Dim intNdeCnt As Integer = 0
        Dim lstNodeErrs As New List(Of String)

        For Each node1 As XmlElement In nodelist

            '-- Counter
            intNdeCnt += 1

            lstNodeErrs.Add("------ Checking node: " & intNdeCnt)

            TicketNumber = node1("TicketNumber").InnerText.Trim
            Total_Amt = node1("Total_Amt").InnerText.Trim
            Total_Taxes = node1("Total_Taxes").InnerText.Trim
            code = node1("code").InnerText
        Next
        If lstErrs.Count > 0 Then


            MsgBox("Complete but with errors! Check error file.") '& vbCrLf & vbCrLf & Strings.Join(lstErrs.ToArray, vbCrLf))
            fileWriter.WriteLine("Filename:   " & strFilNme)
            fileWriter.WriteLine(vbCrLf)
            fileWriter.WriteLine("Errors:")
            For i As Integer = 0 To lstErrs.Count - 1
                fileWriter.WriteLine(lstErrs(i))
            Next

        Else
            MsgBox("Complete!")
            Exit Sub
        End If

        fileWriter.Close()

    Catch ex As XmlSchemaValidationException
        MsgBox("Complete but with errors! Check error file.")
        fileWriter.WriteLine("[Error]: XmlSchemaValidationException -error!!!!!!")
        fileWriter.WriteLine("LineNumber = {0}", ex.LineNumber)
        fileWriter.WriteLine("LinePosition = {0}", ex.LinePosition)
        fileWriter.WriteLine("Message = {0}", ex.Message)
        fileWriter.WriteLine("Source = {0}", ex.Source)

    Catch exOther As Exception
        MsgBox("Complete but with errors! Check error file.")
        fileWriter.WriteLine("[Error]: " & exOther.Message & exOther.StackTrace)

    Finally

        If Not IsNothing(reader) Then
            reader.Close()
        End If

        If Not IsNothing(fileWriter) Then
            fileWriter.Close()
        End If

    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub ValidationEventHandler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ValidationEventArgs)

    'MsgBox("Display Errors")
    Select Case e.Severity
        Case XmlSeverityType.Error
            lstErrs.Add("Error: {0} " & e.Message)
        Case XmlSeverityType.Warning
            lstErrs.Add("Warning {0} " & e.Message)
        Case Else
            lstErrs.Add(e.Message)

    End Select
End Sub

Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click

    Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
    doc.Load(path & FileXml)
    Dim Nodes = doc.SelectNodes("//TicketNumber")
    For Each elem As XmlElement In Nodes

        If elem.InnerText = TextBox1.Text Then
            elem.ParentNode.ParentNode.RemoveChild(elem.ParentNode)
            MessageBox.Show("Element Deleted! ") '& TicketNumber.ToString)           

        End If
    Next
    doc.Save(path & FileXml)
End Sub
```

End Class

> the first button is to read in the txt file, the second for the schema validator and the third for the delete elements. I have a text box also for the ticket number removal

Comment: Your line `Exit For`, will ensure that the loop will exit once you find the first matching element.  What do you mean by "try to delete the second or third"?  Are you clicking `Button5` multiple times (like a "next" button)?

Comment: if I run my code and decide I want to delete ticket number 0145191647505 (which i was refering to as the second set of xml data) it wont delete. However if I put ticket number 0145191647504 (The first set of xml data ) it works prefect. If I put in or take out the exit for I still have the same problem.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the line `For Each elem As XmlElement In Nodes`.  For your second set of xml data, see how many elements are in `Nodes`.  Step-debug-into your loop and hover-over the values, to see if each `elem` has a matching value.

Comment: there are the correct amount of nodes. when I put  a breakpoint at If elem.InnerText = TextBox1.Text Then, I get 0145191647504 when I hover over InnerText and 0145191647505 when I hover over TextBox1. I also put in  "Console.WriteLine(elem.InnerText)" after the line For Each elem As XmlElement In Nodes, and it listed all the correct nodes to the console

Comment: Do you get the "Element Deleted!" messagebox for each node too?

Comment: I only get that message when I try to delete 0145191647504 (the first set of xml) but any other ticket number no I dont. nothing happens.

Comment: Could be a text padding issue. Try `If Trim(elem.InnerText) = Trim(TextBox1.Text) Then` inside of your loop instead of your current compare.

Comment: thanks, I tried this still have the same problem.

Comment: would it help if i uploaded my full code

Comment: This might be a path problem. This really sounds like you think you are opening & saving one file, but checking results in another. Your statement `doc.Load(path & FileXml)`, from your declarations would be looking for a file `filepathxmlfile.xml`. If you are looking at `filepath\xmlfile.xml`, it will not show any results.

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer to use the XDocument Class which was implemented in .Net 3.5.

Given that:

- Your XML structure  is always the same
- You are using .Net 3.5 or newer

I coded something like this to only delete the row I select with the String "deleteme" which can be your "TextBox1.Text".

As I wrote it, it would delete every  containing the given string. If you are sure that you only have one entry with the given string you can enter an "Exit For" command as you did in your example.

```
    Dim tst_xml_path = "MyPath"
    Dim deleteme As String = ("0145191647505")
    Dim doc As New XDocument()


    doc = XDocument.Load(tst_xml_path & "tst.xml")
    For Each elem In doc.<sales_audit_xml>.<DataTable>
        If elem.<TicketNumber>.Value = deleteme Then
            MsgBox("Element " & elem.<TicketNumber>.Value & " deleted!")
            elem.<TicketNumber>.Remove()
        End If
    Next

    Console.WriteLine(doc.ToString)
    doc.Save(tst_xml_path & "tst.xml")
```

So I tried your full code with the following edits:

```
    Public Sub Button5_Click() 'Removed the params to call the function easily.

    Dim deleteme As String = ("01451947504") 'Debug Var for string comapre
    Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
    doc.Load(path & FileXml)

    Dim Nodes = doc.SelectNodes("//TicketNumber")
    For Each elem As XmlElement In Nodes
        If elem.InnerText = deleteme Then
            elem.ParentNode.ParentNode.RemoveChild(elem.ParentNode)
            MsgBox("Element Deleted! ", MsgBoxStyle.Critical) '& TicketNumber.ToString)  'Edited the MessageBox         
        End If
    Next
    doc.Save(path & "ouput.xml") 'Edited the ouput file for debug purpose
End Sub
```

I simply call it in my main function like this...

```
Dim Tst = New Form1
Tst.Button5_Click()
```

And everything went fine. I can delete every of the 3 DataTables you wrote in your example XML file...

Comment: when I tried this code I recieved the error  Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.

Comment: This got two little problems with your xml data. First: you need to end the section <sales_audit_xml> Second: Don't put in the header line in the String. This won't work

Comment: I am looking to read in my xml file, as it will be a large xml file

Comment: when I tried that I recieved the error Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1. I would like to also be able to write the code into a text box

Comment: Can you tell me what exactly are you parsing right now? I created a textfile with the xml as you wrote it in you post. I see that you fixed it. Is the error occupiering while loading your full document, or a test document just containing the lines you wrote in your question post?

Comment: Ahh! Do you copied the leading space? That could cause trouble.

Comment: doc = XDocument.Parse(xmldoc) is the line I recieve the error

Comment: Do you load the string or already a file? Open a file with the XDocument.Load() function, parse a string with the XDocument.Parse() function.

Comment: when I ran your updated code it worked with no errors but still leaves me with my original problem of not deleting any other ticket number other than 0145191647504

Comment: What do you like to delete? the whole <DataTable> containing the ticket number "deleteme" or just the line <TicketNumber> and nothing else in the <DataTable>?

Comment: I tried it now with a few more lines in the xml file and i can perfectly choose which Item i'd like to delete. Are we even talking about the same problem? Have you verified that the lines, which you can't delete, are not in another subsection? My code would not reach trough any new level. Every <DataTable> Item needs to be a direct child from <sales_audit_xml>

Comment: so the code only works for whats in each set <DataTable>? I have my xml formatted as above. yes same problem. but for some reason I have it and you dont when u run the code?

Comment: deleteme as String = ("0145192428666") would delete the line <TicketNumber>0145192428666</TicketNumber> in the XML file you uploaded. NOTHING more. Does it do this when you run it? Or what happens when you test it with JUST the xml file you uploaded?

Comment: Since it seems to be a GUI you programmed it could be a bit too much... Can you send me an e-mail to siwuzu@quick-mail.online with the code and the xml file? You should anonymise your name and pathnames etc. first

Comment: I have uploaded the full code. and explained form design layout. thankyou so so much for taking the time to help

Comment: I just ran it with the following code:         Dim deleteme As String = ("01451947504")
        Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
        doc.Load(path & FileXml)

        Dim Nodes = doc.SelectNodes("//TicketNumber")
        For Each elem As XmlElement In Nodes
            If elem.InnerText. = deleteme Then
                elem.ParentNode.ParentNode.RemoveChild(elem.ParentNode)
                MsgBox("Element Deleted! ", MsgBoxStyle.Critical) '& TicketNumber.ToString)           
            End If
        Next
        doc.Save(path & "ouput.xml")    And it worked perfecly as you want it

Comment: I edited my post to show you what i edited in your code.

Comment: thank you so much but when I try to delete 0145191647505 it still doesnt work. I dont understand how this can be. also I love the MsgBoxStyle.Critical never knew how to do that!

Comment: After much more testing i realy can't get it... I just got one idea left. i once had a problem saving nad flushing my xml files before closing. The main problem were several lines missing in the generated xml, because i havn't called the .flush() and .close() functions. I hope you find your error sometime soon. And always be sure to look at the right output file!

Comment: Thankyou so much for your help I solves it there was a linefeed character getting in the way. solved now thanks so muc!!!